# How do you style an ActiveAdmin input :hint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm unable to find any documentation on styling ActiveAdmin input `:hint`s, short of adding a new styled `div` or using a `status_tag`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this,

1. Adding html_attributes in the field tag.
   https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/fields/base.rb#L126
2. Adding `css_class`

```
field :your_field do
  css_class do
    # Be sure to not remove the original class 
    # set by #{self.name}_field
    "#{self.name}_field your_custom_class"
  end
end
```

3. Including rails assets pipeline in your gem.
   http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#adding-assets-to-your-gems
   https://github.com/railsadminteam/rails_admin/issues/738

Comment: Isn't `css_class` for the field itself? How would I target the `:hint`?